# Magento 2.1 adding custom layout fails?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, custom

Recently I decided to create a custom layout like column1-without-sidebar or something.

I just want **catalog->category** page with the header and footer but without the sidebar etc.

So  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Also I wonder where the default Magento 2.1 column1,2,3 layout is located?

> **I created a file named smakenLayout.xml** in the
>   **/magento2/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/MY_THEME/Magento_Theme/layout**.
>   The code is as follow(taken from magento.stackechange):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Another file which was to declare the smakenLayout.xml was made and put in the main Magento-theme folder: /magento2/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/MY_THEME/Magento_Theme/. The code is as follow:

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="smakenLayout">
        <label translate="true">Test Layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the category page have no sidebars, you can just change the page layout to `1column`. To do this make the file `{theme_directory}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

</page>
```

The different layouts can be found in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/`.

If instead you want to make a new page layout, you'd put `smakenLayout.xml` in `{theme_dir}/Magento_Theme/page_layout/`, not `{theme_dir}/Magento_Theme/layout/`.

Comment: I already tried to change to different column layouts in the admin panel but I still get html content from the sidebar. Also, I only want to remove the sidebar in 1 category page. So I geuss I have to make a new page layout, don't I? EDIT: page_layout doesn't exist in my theme's directory structure only layout.

Comment: If you want to change the layout for just the one category, in admin panel go to that category and under **Design > Layout** select 1 column. You need to create the page_layout directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: It worked! I put the smakenLayout.xml in the newly created page_layout and it worked ! BUT, I don't understand why it worked now because in the 1 column layout, some of the sidebar content transferred to main column and when I chose 1column with sidebar, the same content that transferred was also in the sidebar. So what exactly did I do different this time? In the smakenLayout file I used empty as layout. I geuss If I choose 1column again I will get the same issue as before but why?